# Sharepoint Calculated Field Function Reference

Tags: sharepoint

Is there a definitive list for all of the functions available for a Sharepoint Calculated Field?

Comment: Calculated Column Cheat Sheet -http://blog.pentalogic.net/2011/05/sharepoint-calculated-column-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/CH011711171033.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The closest I've found is:

Math and comparison:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/HA011608661033.aspx?pid=CH011711541033

and

Formulas: 
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/HA011609471033.aspx?pid=CH011711541033

Comment: Yeah, I found each of those via google.

Comment: Both links are broken